# Verifying Access Token in Middleware in LoopBack.js

Tags: node.js, api, acl, loopbackjs, middleware

I am new to loopback.js coming from Express.
I am creating a small API. I have created custom middleware functions and would like to have the ACL verification logic in the middleware.

I used the loopback cli for creating the acl `slc loopback:acl`
However, the accesstoken that I am sending with my POST request does not get verified in the middleware where the DB queries reside. This poses a security concern and I am sure we always do the token verification at the start of the middleware chain.

Can someone help me understand how I can do that?
Will I have to write my own function for this or is there a way to automate it using the loopback framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loopback.token()` middleware to explicitly verify access token in custom apis. [Reference](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html#making-authenticated-requests-with-access-tokens)